# Best residential aquarium test kits for accuracy versus affordability

Tags: aquarium, saltwater, water-parameters, reef-tank

What are the the best testing strips out there for measuring pH, ammonia, nitrates, etc.? I would like to find something more accurate (currently I'm using API test kits with droppers in 5 mL). It seems odd to me that the assumed accuracy and tight parameters that one needs to keep to maintain a mixed reef that API's kits are even suggested to anyone from the LFS. I would like to know if someone has better and more accurate results from other testing kits for their aquarium.

My setup is a mixed reef marine aquarium and eventually my next larger tank might be seeded with this 75G (around 280 liters) I have now. That aquarium will have controllers that will have top shelf controllers with industrial grade probes. I don't have that now. What I have is bottom of the barrel test kits though, monitoring my few thousands dollars worth investment.

Again, does anyone know of a more accurate kit?

Comment: The kit you are using now, are it those paper strips you have to put in water, or is it a liquid testkit?

Comment: It's API's master liquid test kit with Nitrite, Nitrate, Ammonia, and pH. https://tinyurl.com/lnr2c3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After disparate results each time I tested with APIs test kits, I decided to switch to Red Sea, you can [buy kits for marine care on amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BAVVD6I).

I'm very happy with the results they produce and they read better and with far smaller error tolerance.